# Discord.py Python Program Returning KeyError

Tags: python, discord.py, keyerror

I have recently been working on a python project with programming a discord bot. First I will post my Main.py file, then the error I was having:

```
import configparser
import os  
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks 
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import asyncio
#array to send messages to minetest from discord  
minetest_messages = []
  
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
#you may need to path to bot.conf
config.read('bot.conf')    
#settings 
bot = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix=config["BOT"]["command_prefix"], 
  help_command=None, 
  intents=discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True)
)   

lua_file = config["RELAY"]["lua_file_path"]
python_file = config["RELAY"]["python_file_path"]
python_report_file = config["RELAY"]["report_file_path"]
relay_channel = config["RELAY"]["relay_channel"] 
report_channel = config["RELAY"]["report_channel"]
cooldown = config["RELAY"]["cooldown"]
debug_channel = config["RELAY"]["debug_channel"]
debug_file = config["RELAY"]["debug_action_file_path"]

def get_reports_msg():
    if os.path.getsize(python_report_file) != 0: 
        messages = []
        with open(python_report_file, 'r') as filehandle:
            for message in filehandle: 
                messages.append(message)  
                #configs.append(currentPlace)
                
            #once readed empty file's input
            file = open(python_report_file, 'w')
            file.write("")
            file.close()     
                
        return messages
      
      
def get_messages(): 
    #check if file has input or is empty
    if os.path.getsize(lua_file) != 0:   
        messages = []
        with open(lua_file, 'r') as filehandle:
            for message in filehandle: 
                messages.append(message) 
                #configs.append(currentPlace)
                
            #once readed empty file's input
            file = open(lua_file, 'w')
            file.write("")
            file.close()     
                
        return messages 
  
def get_debug_message(): 
    #check if file has input or is empty
    if os.path.getsize(debug_file) != 0:   
        messages = []
        with open(debug_file, 'r') as filehandle:
            for message in filehandle: 
                messages.append(message) 
                #configs.append(currentPlace)
                
            #once readed empty file's input
            file = open(debug_file, 'w')
            file.write("")
            file.close()     
                
        return messages 
  
def write_messages():
    #check if discord has messages to send and if so empty the array and send 
    if os.path.getsize(python_file) == 0:
        #once readed empty file's input
        file = open(python_file, 'a')
        for dmsg in (minetest_messages):
            file.write("{} \n".format(dmsg))
                        
        file.close()
        minetest_messages.clear()


@bot.event     
async def on_ready():  
    print('Connected!')
    #start the loop   
    task_loop.start()
     

#fetch messages in the channel
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #make sure the channel is the right one and the bot messages getting ignored
    if (message.channel.id == int(relay_channel)) and (message.author.id != bot.user.id):
        author = message.author.name
        if config["RELAY"]["use_nicknames"] == True:
            author = message.author.display_name
        
        msg = "[Discord] <{}> {}".format(author, message.content)
        minetest_messages.append(msg)  
        
    
#loop to check if file has input or not
@tasks.loop(seconds=int(cooldown))
async def task_loop():
    #incase of an timeout
    try:
        channel = await bot.fetch_channel(relay_channel)
        rep_channel = await bot.fetch_channel(report_channel)
        deb_channel = await bot.fetch_channel(debug_channel)
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        
    #check if channel exists
    if channel is None:
        print("Error: Channel id {}, dosn't exists".format(channel)) 
    elif rep_channel is None:
        print("Error: Channel id {}, dosn't exists".format(rep_channel))
    elif debug_channel is None:
        print("Error: Channel id {}, dosn't exists".format(debug_channel))
        
     
    #get messages from lua.txt
    messages = get_messages() 
    report_msg = get_reports_msg()
    debug_msg = get_debug_message()
    
    #Read / send messages
    if messages != None:    
        for msg in (messages):  
            await channel.send(msg) 
    
    if report_msg != None:
        for rmsg in (report_msg):
            await rep_channel.send(rmsg)    

    if debug_msg != None:
        for dmsg in (debug_msg):
            await deb_channel.send(dmsg)  
            
    #only write if array isn't emtpy
    if len(minetest_messages) != 0:
        write_messages() 
    

#bot token to run
bot.run(config["TutorialBot"]["MTEyOTM4MDQ2OTU3ODkyNDEwMw.GL2azN.BI1Q54MHF8HnCdf-y5D3cVyEo-l-4vTRCQNvqs"])
```

I am running up against 1 error that I need a little help resolving (see the following):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/Downloads/discordmt_bot-main/Main.py", line 154, in <module>
    bot.run(config["TutorialBot"]["<discord account key combination here"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'TutorialBot'
```

I can provide some of the external files if necessary (this was the only python file) I am inclined to think this error only relates to the python part of the project.
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

I am relatively new to python, and have not previously learnt a programming language, so all I knew to do was navigate to my python installation and look in the file that was giving the error, but didn't see anything "out of place".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Going by the documentation for configparser, seems like you did not write the necessary configurations in `bot.conf`.

Python expects this file to follow the format of a `.ini` file, which is as follows:

```
[section1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
...

[section2]
...
```

In this case you are trying to access a section called "`TutorialBot`", and from that section, the value of a key named "`<discord account key combination here`", which doesn't exist in the `bot.conf` file.

It seems like you are trying to configure a token for your discord bot, so here is a solution:

**bot.conf**:

```
[Credentials]
Token = TOKEN
```

Then, to access the value `TOKEN` you supply, use `config["Credentials"]["Token"]`

As you can see, this will look inside the section called "`Credentials`", and then access the value of the key called "`Token`". Of course, you should substitute `TOKEN` with the actual token. You also don't need to use the section/key names that I provided, I was just giving an example.

Comment: Thanks for helping me see my error. It was right in front of me! Thanks so much for your help.